# MetricsExtension.Native.Exe is not running when deploy Geneva monitoring agent on service fabric

Tags: monitoring, agent, geneva-server

The problem is:

1. Received service fabric metrics should be under new namespace, but still under old namespace;
2. A measure metric didn't appear.
   Config:

Comment: <Extensions>
      <Extension extensionName="MetricsExtension">
        <CommandLine><![CDATA[MetricsExtension.Native.exe -FrontEndUrl https://metrics-int.dc.ad.msft.net/]]></CommandLine>
        <ResourceUsage 
          cpuPercentUsage="10"
          workingSetThrottling="true"
          workingSetLimitInMB="1000"
          memoryLimitInMB="1000"
          memoryThrottling="true" />
      </Extension>
    </Extensions>

Comment: You can click on the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54718937/edit)** link below your post to add your code. Codes are hard to read from the comments.